# Increasing the view of observable universe

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, space-expansion, observable-universe

I have read that the maximum observable universe is about 92 billion light years in diameter by measuring the microwave background waves emitted after some few million years ago from the big bang and they are reaching us now due to the expansion of universe.

So, my question is can we increase our total view of the observable universe let's say by sending a hypothetical space probe with the speed of light in any one direction and now the light wave reaching to that probe will be almost 2x more than here on earth, so will it increase our view.

Comment: Otherwise said, yes it is supposed that if we choose another center, there will be there another and similar observable universe. All the rest is analogue to sitting here and just wait. Unless communication with the probe is also hypothetical and instantaneous

Comment: I think this method won't increase "observable universe" that much. Because if you send your space probe too far, its signal won't reach you at all due to the expansion of universe. and if you keep it too close, then you won't see much more. Of course I have assumed that your probe is fast enough to go far in short time.

Comment: Let’s say the probe is mapping the observable universe on its own and if we look at the observable universe view on earth plus the view of universe created by space probe itself (btw I am assuming at the same time) then we will have somehow have increased view